# Facebook Send Dialog issue (I get the generic error, even for the most basic send link)

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I get the following error:

```
An error occurred. Please try again later.
```

When I click this link locally (localhost is the location for my local server):

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=384485768250619&link=http://localhost:3000&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/profile
```

I'm not even able to find a facebook logs to figure out what exactly the error is. This generic error for such a basic link is incredibly frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out: apparently Facebook doesn't allow localhost as an acceptable host for the link parameter. Very strange!